# Extending HTMLOptionsCollection

Tags: javascript

I want to extend the javascript object htmloptionscollection.
How can I accomplish this?
I already tried many websites with solutions but none worked in every browser I have.
(Mozilla firefox, Mozilla seamonkey, Opera, google chrome, IE9)

Code requested

```
HTMLOptionsCollection.prototype.contains = HTMLOptionsCollection.prototype.contains ||
    function(otherOption) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            if (this[i].value === otherOption.value) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HTMLOptionsCollection` is a host object. You cannot safely extend it.

See http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/#host_objects_have_no_rules for the "why".

> Next problem with DOM extension is that DOM objects are host objects, and host objects are the worst bunch. By specification (ECMA-262 3rd. ed), host objects are allowed to do things, no other objects can even dream of. To quote relevant section [8.6.2]:
>
> > Host objects may implement these internal methods with any implementation-dependent behaviour, or it may be that a host object implements only some internal methods and not others.

Comment: How can I find documentation stating how to do wrappers in javascript. I know jquery and other frameworks exist but I want to do that on my own also in order to learn how to program javascript properly.

Comment: how can I accomplish what's commented above this (learn how to create object wrappers)